# Add prefix to io.Reader

Tags: go

I've written a little server which receives a blob of data in the form of an `io.Reader`, adds a header and streams the result back to the caller.

My implementation isn't particularly efficient as I'm buffering the blob's data in-memory so that I can calculate the blob's length, which needs to form part of the header.

I've seen some examples of `io.Pipe()` with `io.TeeReader` but they're more for splitting an `io.Reader` into two, and writing them away in parallel.

The blobs I'm dealing with are around 100KB, so not huge but if my server gets busy, memory's going to quickly become an issue...

Any ideas?

```
func addHeader(in io.Reader) (out io.Reader, err error) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if _, err = io.Copy(buf, in); err != nil {
        return
    }

    header := bytes.NewReader([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("header:%d", buf.Len())))

    return io.MultiReader(header, buf), nil
}
```

I appreciate it's not a good idea to return interfaces from functions but this code isn't destined to become an API, so I'm not too concerned with that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the only way to determine the length of data in an io.Reader is to read until EOF. There are ways to determine the length of the data for specific types.

```
func addHeader(in io.Reader) (out io.Reader, err error) {
  n := 0
  switch v := in.(type) {
  case *bytes.Buffer:
    n = v.Len()
  case *bytes.Reader:
    n = v.Len()
  case *strings.Reader:
    n = v.Len()
  case io.Seeker:
    cur, err := v.Seek(0, 1)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    end, err := v.Seek(0, 2)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, err = v.Seek(cur, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    n = int(end - cur)
  default:
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    if _, err := buf.ReadFrom(in); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    n = buf.Len()
    in = &buf
  }
  header := strings.NewReader(fmt.Sprintf("header:%d", n))
  return io.MultiReader(header, in), nil
}
```

This is similar to how the net/http package [determines the content length of the request body](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/497b608faba2a9c450d03e2bca2ef005ea32b933/src/net/http/request.go#L789-L817).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cerise.  It's an io.ReadCloser under the covers, so I guess I'll just have to buffer it.  Cheers!

Comment: @Rob io.ReadCloser is an interface type. The concrete type is something else.  Try `fmt.Println("%T", in)` to see what the concrete type is. Perhaps it will be one of the types listed in my answer or one that you can extract the length from without reading it.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll check the underlying implementation and see if I can extract the length.  Thanks very much!